# SVG background gradient on mobile phones not showing like my desktop

Tags: css, mobile, svg, background, repeat

**UPDATED WITH SVG CODE AS REQUESTED!**

I am using the following CSS code in a website:

```
#page-body {
background: url("/images/background/map_gradient.svg") repeat fixed 50% 0 / 100% 1500px, url("/images/background/map_img.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 / 2060px 1010px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px"     viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" xml:space="preserve">
<radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="50" cy="0" r="50" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0"/>
<stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0"/>
<stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
</radialGradient>
<rect y="-50" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" width="100" height="100"/>
<rect y="50" width="100" height="50" fill-opacity="0.3"/>
</svg>
```

A desktop screenshot:

[image: desktop screenshot]

And a mobile screenshot:

[image: mobile screenshot]

I know this isn't a responsive CSS code problem because i can get the same result when i drag the window from pc display to an old hdmi TV display. Can you please suggest me a workaround ?

Comment: This question as it stands is rather unclear, what is wrong precisely? Could you post a complete example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: You cant see the SVG gradient boxes in second screenshot? They don't get stretched to the whole background and they just get repeated...

Comment: What browser, what version of that browser, what OS, what version of the OS? might be good to see the svg code too, even if it's not complex. Note that the stylerule says to repeat the svg image, is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Firefox 31, Windows 8.1 No i just wanted stretched to the background... I saw the repeat there but this is the correct css as i get it from a Joomla Template and works great in my firefox.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Can you please take a look?

Comment: Please update the question with all the details (including what you've tried to fix the problem). This may be a problem with `background-attachment: fixed`. Have you tried using `background-size: cover`?

Comment: I dont think its the css because in the template's [demo](http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2011/bigeasy/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=1&profile=olive) is working without issues:(